# Error while running attempting to start a new project on Django using 'django-admin startproject website'

Tags: python, django, python-3.6

**Basic Information:** I am completely new to Django, and have been attempting to follow their documentation. When I attempt to run the code shown here, it comes up with an error:

```
 django-admin startproject website
```

**Error message:**
django-admin is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. (https://gyazo.com/5159e172f1d0235b49db4fb4a73469cc)

**System Information:** Python version: 3.6.3, Computer Operating System: Windows 10, Django version: 2.0.5

Comment: are you using a `virtual environment`? make sure it's activate

Comment: Such as virtualenv? No, because it also came up with an error message.

Comment: Error found here: https://gyazo.com/83b83288d75b0df95e979e6679195346

Comment: `virtualenv env_name` then swith to that directory and type `source bin/activate` **Linux Users**

Comment: I'm a windows user, and same error.

Comment: `virtualenv env_name` then swith to that directory and type scripts\activate **Windows Users**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Firstly,

- Check wether *django-admin.py* file is in ***'PythonXX\Scripts'*** folder and that folder is added to *System Environment Variables*, ***(PATH)*** of Windows 10.
- If not, it can be added with  `C:\> set PATH=%PATH%;C:\PythonXX\;C:\PythonXX\Scripts\`

**2)** If that does not work;

- **Setup a virtual environment** named *ANY*, in the directory where you want to start your django project: `C:\some_path> python -m venv ANY`.
- **Start the virtual environment:** `C:\some_path\ANY\Scripts\activate.bat`. If things went right, name of the running virtual environment will be included at the beginning of the command line prompt like: `(ANY) C:\some_path\ANY\Scripts>`
- If django is not installed into the running virtual environment, no django application will be recognized and be able to run by the command line.
  Therefore, **install django:** `(ANY) C:\some_path> python -m pip install django`. It doesn't matter where you ran that last code, in a running virtual environment.
- The virtual environment must be started before running any django application.
- **Start a django project**: `(ANY) C:\some_path> django-admin startproject website`

I hope those helps...Good luck.

Comment: This may be a bad question, but am I cding to start the virtual env? If so, it comes up with the error 'The directory name is invalid'

Comment: You typed `cd C:\some_path\ANY\Scripts\activate.bat` am i  right? If so, that code is not for cding. But if your purpose is  changing your working directory to ‘C:\some_path\ANY\Scripts’ in the command line and run `activate.bat`, than run `cd C:\some_path\ANY\Scripts` and after just type `activate.bat`

Comment: I’m glad. You’re wellcome.